# Packets not routed through openvpn tunnel in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn

I'm setting up an openvpn server on an aws ec2 instance. This instance has two interfaces :

- One interface belonging to a private subnet (10.10.0.0/17)
- One interface belonging to a public subnet (10.10.128.0/17)

My goal is to allow traffic from the internet to communicate with the instances that are in the private subnet, through the VPN.
[Here is a schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8O2E.png)

The connection is well established between outside and the public interface. It is also established between the private interface and the instances that are in the private subnet.

The problem appears when i try to ping private instances from an outer client. I can see the "initialization sequence completed" message, but no traffic seems to be routed through the tunnel. Actually no route at all seems found, even when the destination is the vpn server itself :

[traceroute to server tun interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQy51.png)

[connexion logging on client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh3mx.png)

[connexion logging on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fLzJ.png)

Even though there seems to be errors when the route is created, it is present in the kernel routing table so I guess the problem doesn't come from here :

[route command on client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPvC0.png)

Here is my client configuration :

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote <server_ip> 1194
route 10.10.0.0 255.255.128.0
nobind
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo 
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<SNIP>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
Certificate:
<SNIP>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<SNIP>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<SNIP>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<SNIP>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

And the server one :

```
local 0.0.0.0 

port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server.key  

dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/dh.pem

topology subnet

server 10.10.0.0 255.255.128.0

#client-to-client communication
duplicate-cn

keepalive 10 120

cipher AES-256-CBC

comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3

mute 10

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

I've followed the openvpn howto from begin to start and really don't know what I'm missing. Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand with a diagram and your terms like "outer traffic" defined. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. Two question 1) Have you considered EC2 source / destination check? 2) Have you considered using the AWS managed VPN?

Comment: Just added a schema to the post. Outer traffic means traffic coming from the internet. 1) I don't understand your question 2) Yes and I'd prefer not use it because it's both expensive and not personalizable enough

Comment: AWS VPN is about $36 per month, expensive for playing with but cheap for a corporate / business given the redundancy and such. Have a read of this whole page especially the section I link directly to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck  . A VPN is a bit like a NAT in that it's not the source or destination for traffic "Each EC2 instance performs source/destination checks by default. This means that the instance must be the source or destination of any traffic it sends or receives..."

Comment: I'm building an app that will hold multiple VPN instances, and really can't afford $36 per server given the amount. I disabled the source/destination checking, but didn't change anything. And actually that was pretty expected because the VPN traffic isn't even routed through the tunnel - as it was said in the title. See the traceroute screenshot.

Comment: I can't help with OpenVPN, just AWS. AWS VPN charges allow two incoming VPNs and that covers communication with every resource in your VPC, but only to two targets / destinations outside your VPC. If you're connecting many branches / resources to the VPN then I can see why you want many VPNs, but I wonder if you could manage with application level encryption - but you haven't said what you're trying to achieve, just how you want to do it.